# Blend two color attachments together into final image

Tags: vulkan

If I have multiple color attachments, it is said I can blend those together for the final image to be presented.

I understand how to configure fixed blending functions with:

```
    VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState
    VkPipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo
```

The question is, if I say `VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ZERO` and `VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ONE`, which color attachment is source, which destination? Where can I specify them, if I have 3 attachments (2 color + 1 depth-stencil) like this:

```
    { colorAttachment1, colorAttachment2, depthImage }
```

Say, I want to blend `colorAttachment2` over `colorAttachment1` because only `colorAttachment1` is presentable while the other is not, it's just an "internal" image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "blending of color attachments". Blending happens between the current value in an attachment and the fragment color(s) generated for a specific fragment.

If you have two framebuffer attached images, and you want to blend between them, what you need to do is render a full-screen quad in such a way that you're reading from one attachment in the FS and writing (with blending) to the other. You would have to read from one of the attachments as an input attachment, so you need to put this rendering command in a new subpass.

If you're writing to a third image (which isn't ideal, since you have one more image than you need), then you can just read from both images, do the blending in the shader with regular math, and write to the third.

Comment: I see. But at that point I can maybe avoid it altogether. The blending I need is MAYBE commutative (I need more time to think about it better). I could first clear with ambient light color, render light quads with proper blending and then render sprite quads with proper blending. This way I only need one attachment and image/memory. But this "recipe" is strictly in sequence, no way to leverage parallelism later on. Just on a general level, does this sound reasonable? I can't find any tutorials but this OpenGL, where code is TOTALLY different: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsE1ddOas7A

Comment: The thing is I would first render sprites and then blend in light, but if it's commutative there's no need for a second image to blend-over. I could just blend-under (I have no name for this idea).

Comment: There is also a feature called [dual source blending](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#framebuffer-dsb), its widely available and lets you have two values outputted by [fragment shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending#Dual_Source_Blending) and used as blend factors.